# ¿Como cambiar el valor del find en una tabla con un popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el siguiente problema, abro una ventana emergente. al presionar el boton guardar esta actualiza el tr actual de la tabla. Esto lo hace muy bien con esto:

```
parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
                             parent.find('td, th').css('background-color', '#58ACFA');
```

Pero dentro de esta ventana emergente tengo un botón que va al siguiente registro.

Con este código obitne el sigueinte registro sin problema:

```
parent = linkObj.closest("tr").next('tr');
```

Pero si quiero llegar hasta el tercero ya no me deja.

intente hacer un foreach para ver si le iba asignando el siguiente parent al objeto.

Pero el .next solo obtiene el siguiente a partir del orginal:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= contador; i++)
                          {
                              parent = linkObj.closest("tr").next('tr');
```

¿Cual seria la forma correcta de hacer esto?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa es hacer uso de una variable para detectar la posición de tu fila y a partir de ahí incrementar su valor +1 en caso de que se presione el botón que va al siguiente registro.

luego con esa variable podes acceder a la fila, porque esa variable corresponde al indice de tu fila

[mira el siguiente ejemplo que arme](https://jsfiddle.net/hcmenc31/14/)

```
var position = 0;

$('.link').click(function() {
  position = $('tbody tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));
  $('tbody').find('tr').eq(position).css('background-color','#58ACFA');  
});

$('.btn').click(function() {
  ++position;
  $('tbody').find('tr').eq(position).css('background-color','#58ACFA');  
});
```

la función `eq` devuelve el elemento que coincida con ese indice en el selector y ahí le aplicas el estilo

el botón next que puse fuera de la tabla, es el botón que va al siguiente registro

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Mauro.

Añadi lo siguiente al código y quedo perfecto

if (recorremodal == 0)
                 {
       parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
       parent.find('td, th').css('background-color','#58ACFA');
                 }

```
             else
               {

                      $('tbody').find('tr').eq(recorremodal).css('background-color', '#58ACFA');

                     }
```